# QGIS and ArcGIS on the same PC

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, installation

I work for a small non profit conservation organization  and we have a reasonably high turnover of people... so it stands to reason that some people don't want to change from a preferred program.
this in mind...

Can i install ArcGIS 10.1 and QGIS on the same PC without problems?

Comment: Of course. Those are entirely different programs and if you install QGIS with the OSGEO4W installer it runs entirely within a folder. But of course with every software it depends on your system specifications and the context you are using them.

Answer (score 5):

<s>As per [this question](http://qandasys.info/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-to-work-in-both-qgis-and-arcgis/), you can.</s>

Edit: The link above is to the domain qandasys.info which appears to be either temporarily or permanently taken over by bad actors. I don't know for sure if it's appropriate that I delete the link.

As the link describes, you'll have to point the Python path for both suites.

Comment: Please be careful with the link above. Ideally the author can find a new link to the same or equivalent information. Or more ideally, knowledge from the original source could be included in the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS uses it's own Python path, which gets set when you launch QGIS (this should be done automatically). But if you are having issues with Python in QGIS try launching it from the QGIS.bat file from *\OSGeo4W\bin* or *\QGIS install path\bin*, depending on the installation location.

ArcGIS takes over the system one.

So you are fine to have both installed.